# Find duplicates in CONCAT DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

```
TempTable(Ncol1, Ncol2) as 
(SELECT
   col1,
    SUBSTR(xmlserialize(xmlagg(xmltext(CONCAT( ', ', col2))) as VARCHAR(1024)), 3) AS ConcatCol2
    FROM Table A
    WHERE A.col2 IN ('A','B','C','D')
    and A.Date >= (select FirstDayMonth from dates)
    GROUP BY A.col1)
```

In the table A the column col2 have the values like this:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I have the code above that `concat` like this `ABCD` but it repeats just one of the values something like this `ABCDD`.
I tried DISTINCT in subquery like I read in another topic here, but what's the other solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your db2 version and platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `LISTAGG(DISTINCT` the `ORDER BY` needs to be the same as the LISTAGG clause

So this works

```
SELECT 
    col1
,   LISTAGG(DISTINCT CONCAT( ', ', col2)) WITHIN GROUP 
           (ORDER BY CONCAT( ', ', col2))
FROM TableA
WHERE
    col2 IN ('A','B','C','D')
GROUP BY
    col1
```

but this

```
SELECT 
    col1
,   LISTAGG(DISTINCT CONCAT( ', ', col2)) WITHIN GROUP 
           (ORDER BY               col2 )
FROM TableA
WHERE
    col2 IN ('A','B','C','D')
GROUP BY
    col1
```

gets

> An expression in the ORDER BY clause in the following position, or starting with "CONCAT..." in the "ORDER BY" clause is not valid.  Reason code = "2".. SQLCODE=-214, SQLSTATE=42822

and, as expected, this is noted in the manual page for [LISTAGG](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058709.html)

> If DISTINCT is specified for LISTAGG, the sort-key of the ORDER BY specification must match string-expression (SQLSTATE 42822). If string-expression is implicitly cast, the sort-key must explicitly include a corresponding matching cast specification.

Answer (score 1):

Try `LISTAGG(DISTINCT )`

```
CREATE TABLE T(C VARCHAR(32))

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('A'),('B'),('B'),('C')

SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT C) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY C) FROM T
```

will return

```
    1     
------
ABC
```

You will need to be on DB2 11.1 or above for `DISTINCT` option in [`LISTAGG`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0058709.html)

Comment: Hey, that doesn't work, I don't know which my version is, here is my code:

TempTable(Ncol1, Ncol2) as 
(SELECT
   col1,
    LISTAGG(DISTINCT (CONCAT( ', ', col2))) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY col2) 
    FROM Table A
    WHERE A.col2 IN ('A','B','C','D')
    and A.Date >= (select FirstDayMonth from dates)
    GROUP BY A.col1)

Comment: You can find the DB2 version of your sever with this query. SELECT SERVICE_LEVEL FROM SYSIBMADM.ENV_INST_INFO